# Group Rows in SSRS Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Im not super familiar with SSRS yet. I have a tablix that has a list of responses, count of responses, and percentage of responses.[image: Tablix]

the right most expression calculates the percentage of how many times an answer appears. It doesnt include No Reponse.  I want to merge The right most column into one row so No response is included

Comment: It would help a lot to see the expressions used here and the query that you are using to get the data.  Also helpful would be an idea of how the data is laid out in the database.  I'm thinking you'd be better off calculating most of these fields in the database, but more info is necessary before I can really help.

Comment: Why don't you inject 'No Response' into your dataset as an `Answer`, then that would be included in the `[Answers]`. But agree with @Steve-o169, show your expressions and also the dataset query would help too.

Comment: Does your `Answers` field have a blank or NULL that is used as the **No Response**? My guess is that the Answers grouping filters out the NULLs while the No Response row only counts them and it could grouped with the others. That expression would help figure it out.